# can i use multiple foreach?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have the following arrays and loop conditions. I cannot preview this output.

Wanted Output: (this doesn't answer the code I provided below)

```
emp_name1 = captamerica  
emp_name2 like ironman
```

my php code:

```
$filter = array('emp_name1','emp_name2');   
$condition = array('=','like');   
$values = array('captamerica','ironman');   

foreach($filter as $row){
    foreach($condition as $row2){
        foreach($values as $row3){
            echo $row." ".$row2." ".$row3."<br>"; 
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Are the 3 arrays always guaranteed to have the same number of elements, and therefore always a component member of each comparison value and operator?

Comment: yes sir. I'm making a sample or idea of the output that I want to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have same element count for each array, which is ok for your data. Here is what you need :

```
foreach($filter as $k=>$row){
  echo $row." ".$condition[$k]." ".$values[$k]."<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as you doing it on different arrays you can do multiple foreach. The reason is that php has internal array pointers which need to be manipulated during a foreach. If you do multiple foreach on the same array the internal pointers will be disturbed.

I don't get the output you have cited. What I get is :

```
emp_name1 = captamerica
emp_name1 = ironman
emp_name1 like captamerica
emp_name1 like ironman
emp_name2 = captamerica
emp_name2 = ironman
emp_name2 like captamerica
emp_name2 like ironman
```

Comment: Did you read the desired output aligning/relating the array keys? Only one loop is needed to produce 2 lines of output, not 8 lines from 3 nested loops.

Comment: The question is not clear. The Title seems to ask a question, that too is written incorrectly. There is a shift key on your keyboard.  Then your inability to 'preview' an output does not suggest that you actually want that output.

Comment: You're right boss. Anyway I can't find a sample of the same idea that I want to happen. But still I'm looking for any source and finding another way to make it...

Comment: sorry man. What I'm showing to my output is what I wanted to came out. my code that I posted doesn't answer the output I provided.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple foraech. but not to display this kink of output.

you have 3 nested loops, each will loop 2 times, which means than echo statement will be executed 2*2*2=8 times.

to print the tow lines you want you will simply need one `for loop` statement.

```
for($i=0;$i<2;$i++)
    echo $filter[$i]." ".$condition[$i]." ".$values[$i]."<br>";
```

Comment: thanks for the help man. This is one of the option I'm thinking.